# How fit to screen inner div container which can change sizes e.g. video of different sizes?

Tags: css, sass

Here is my react component.

```
const Player = require(react-player);

<div className="video-container">
  {activeVideo !== null && (
     <div className="player-aspect-ratio-box">
       <Player
         className="player"
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         url={videos[activeVideo].url}
         playing={true}
         controls
         onEnded={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}
         onError={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}
       />
     </div>
   )}
</div>
```

and sass file

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(60,60,60, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.player-aspect-ratio-box {
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: (9/16)*100%;
  }
  .player {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

as you can see I used aspect ratio box but when video is a portrait size (like 1080x1920) the video width fits to screen 100% but height overflows with scrollbar. So how to fit it to the screen responsively? write css for different kind variants of videos like portrait, landscape? or is there some clever trick?

Answer (score 0):

If legacy browser support isn't a problem, you can use [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property and set a `max-width` and a `max-height`